# NHibernate - Perform step after retrieving database entry

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class that has some metadata attached to it. For example:

```
public class Parameter<T> : IParameter
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public List<IParameter> Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

I have another class which then contains a `IList<IParameter>`

```
public class Bar
{
    public IList<IParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `IUserType` which can store certain types as JSON (such as a `List<IParameter>`). I plan to store the `Bar.Parameters` using this, so the column value would look like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "letter",
        "value": "a",
        "metadata": [
            "options": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "cat.name",
        "value": "Mittens",
        "metadata": [
            "display_name": "Name"
        ]
    }
]
```

However it is unnecessary for me to store the metadata, as it is defined elsewhere and can be retrieved using `Parameter.Id`. I would like to instead store an array of the ids mapped against their values:

```
[
    "letter": "a",
    "cat.name": "Mittens"
]
```

I know how to make the `Parameters` column be written in this way, but I am unsure how I could go about making `Bar` retrieve the metadata once it has been retrieved.

What would be ideal is the something similar to the `OnDeserialized` attribute in WCF. This lets me define a method on `Bar` that is called once it has been deserialized:

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public IList<IParameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        // Extremely simplified example of how the Foo metadata may
        // be retrieved.
        foreach(var parameter in Parameters)
        {
            parameter.Metadata = BarMetadataStore.GetMetadata(Type, parameter.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid manually calling a function on `Bar` to retrieve the metadata as my real `Bar` is part of a large class hierarchy. NHibernate automagically retrieves a `Bar` as part of a join when I retrieve the owning class.

It is also important that `Bar` can perform the "deserialization" step, as other classes use the `Parameter<T>` class and may populate the metadata from a different place to `Bar`.

I was considering using an `IUserType` which loads the metadata in the `NullSafeGet` but the `GetMetadata` is dependent on another property of the `Bar` and I do not know how to get that value in all the necessary places.

In short: Is there something similar to `[OnDeserialized]` in NHibernate/FluentNHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926993/nhibernate-event-listeners) (more specifically, [`IPostLoadEventListener`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Event/IPostLoadEventListener.cs)) is what you're after.

Comment: And the documentation is here:  http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html